# What is the R file format of a dissimilarity matrix and how do I read it in?

Tags: r

I am a very novice R programmer but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  I apologize if this is a newbie question.

I have 435 items and have calculated differences between all of them, giving me a similarity matrix with column and row names and '0' along the diagonal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/E75DW.png).

What is the file format for R so that I can save this out and read it in in R?  And, once I am in R, how do I read it up?  I have used read.csv and read.table but I am not sure I am doing it right, particularly with column and row names, and thus I don't trust the output.  Eventually I want to cluster and pick cluster representatives.

thank you!
Denny

As an example, I am currently saving from a C program out to a CSV file.  It is formatted like the snippet below (the leading ',' is to make sure that the column and row names align on the diagonal).  But I can't figure out how to read this into R to get a 435x435 matrix with named columns and rows.

```
,134424,144077,150472,154222,156937,156941,
134424,0,0.883618248417182,0.974399713412412
144077,0.883618248417182,0,0.774739255322855
150472,0.974399713412412,0.774739255322855,0
```

Comment: I think you'll need to learn to use `read.csv` or similar. Unlike SAS, STATA, et al, I haven't heard of people exporting to R format.

Comment: In a call to `dist()`, you can use the arguments `diag = T, upper = T` to return a full matrix (rather than a lower-triangular matrix). You can then convert this to standard matrix class using `as.matrix()`, and save to .csv or .txt using `write.table()`. You can then read it in again using `read.csv()`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry, to be clear I just need to save my matrix out to a file (from a C program, so the format can be whatever is needed) in *some* format that can be read by R - CSV would be just fine.  I don't want to save it *from* R, I want to save it to disk and read it *into* R.  Using the csv formatting that I showed in the attached image, I just tried read.csv, but dim(x) yielded [1] 435 437, which seems dodgy - it should be 435x435, correct?  (again, sorry for newbie questions).

Comment: see `?read.table`. The `sep` argument allows you to specify the character that separates the cell values in your text/csv file. Open up your file in a text editor and make sure that there is a comma/tab/whatever between every cell value on a given line. The additional columns may come from blank spaces which somehow got appended to your file. If so, these should appear as `NA` values when you `print(matrix_object)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the file in CSV file, say `data.csv`.

You can import into R as a matrix like this:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.csv(file='data.csv', header=F))
```

The `header=F` is important, otherwise the first line in the file is treated as a header, not as part of the data.

Take for example this csv data:

```
,2,3
4,0,6
7,8,
```

Imported to R it will look like:

```
> m <- as.matrix(read.csv(file='data.csv', header=F))
> m
     V1 V2 V3
[1,] NA  2  3
[2,]  4  0  6
[3,]  7  8 NA
```

You can access elements like this:

```
> m[2,1]
V1 
 4 
> m[3,2]
V2 
 8
```

If you want to replace `NA` values with `0`:

```
> m[is.na(m)] <- 0
> m
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  0  2  3
[2,]  4  0  6
[3,]  7  8  0
```

If you want to remove the `V1..V3` column names:

```
> colnames(m) <- NULL
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    3
[2,]    4    0    6
[3,]    7    8    0
```

Comment: also see argument `row.names` in `read.csv` for an analogous problem to a mis-specified header.

Comment: so, thanks, I think this works.  I read somewhere that if R sees that the column header row is one column shorter than the rows of the main body AND you are using column header, it assumes that the extra column  in the main rows is the row name.  Anyway, that seemed to work.  I used as.matrix(x) and now I think I have a matrix with my data - the '0' in the diagonal is at the intersection of row.names = 134424 and 'X134424'.  I guess that means it worked...

Comment: thanks!  your explanations made it a lot more clear.  This is great.